# How to change default app of .html extension in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, default-settings, file-extension

The .html file extension does not show in the default apps settings.
[Here's the screenshot in default apps settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY2k9.png)

Now I tried searching for a solution and tried a program named 'FileTypeDiag' but I can't understand/know what to do with the text file it generated. Here's the link of the text file it generated: https://pastebin.com/wYfTBd51

Comment: html is shown here (Windows 11 Pro).  Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, scroll to bottom (Apps by File Type). In the Window that shows up, search for HTML and it shows up with Edge attached to it.

Comment: Easiest way for any file type I know: Right-click, (bring up the real context menu, ) “Open with”, Choose another app. Does that not work on Windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 allows you to Find and then Change the HTML default.

In Windows 11 Pro: Start, Settings, Apps, Default Apps, scroll to bottom (Apps by File Type). In the Window that shows up, search for HTML and it shows up with Edge attached to it.

See the attached screenshots to help you.

[image: Windows 11 find HTML extension]

.

[image: Windows 11 change default for HTML extensiom]